# popover field validation loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popover

I'm trying to figure out a cool way to go through my DIV fields and using a FOR LOOP validate if they are empty or not and then show a popover warning.

I have already accomplished warning with a * on a SPAN object, but I want now to be able to do the same with a DIV with a name or id like "popoverempty_name" or something.

This is what I got so far:

```js
// After Form Submitted Validation
$("#contact_submit button").click(function(event){
    var form_data=$("#contact input[type=text]").serializeArray();
    var error_free=true;
    for (var input in form_data) {
 var element=$("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name']);
 var valid=element.hasClass("valid");
        var error_element=$("span", element.parent());  

        // This part doesn't work :
        var popover_element=$(this).attr("#popover_"+form_data[input]['name']);  
        // Why???

 if (!valid) {
            error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show"); 
            error_free=false;
            //$('popover_element').popover('show');
        }
 else {
            error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
            //$('popover_element').popover('hide');
        }
    }
    if (!error_free) {
 event.preventDefault(); 
    }
    else {
 alert('No errors: Form will be submitted');
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- Name -->
<div  id="popover1" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Fix your name" data-content="Enter a correct name i.e. John Doe">
    <div id="popoverempty_name" data-toggle="popoverempty" data-placement="left" title="This is Required" data-content="" ></div> 
    <span class="error">ERROR</span>  
    <label for="contact_name"></label>
    <input class="checkout-input checkout-name" placeholder="Name and Lastname" type="text" name="name" id="contact_name" required/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go figure! I solved it by playing around with it a little bit more... and waking up fresh in the morning always helps!! ;-)

Here is the answer... I hope it helps someone out there!

```js
    for (var input in form_data){
     var element=$("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name']);
     var valid=element.hasClass("valid");
     var error_element=$("span", element.parent());
     if (!valid){error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show"); error_free=false;$(function () {$("#popoverempty_"+form_data[input]['name']).popover('show')});}
     else{error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");$(function () {$("#popoverempty_"+form_data[input]['name']).popover('hide')});}
    }
```